# Working WIth Color options in Magento

Tags: magento

I am developing a site for an appliance retailer on Magento, and am wondering if anyone can suggest how I should implement the following:

1. There are multiple colors for each appliance.
2. Each related color has it's own sku, and some price variations.

I'd like to have the following happen:

1. When users browse the catalog they should only see 1 product, but have a list -- with related skus, color and prices in a list , and should be able to navigate to the indivual item
2. I don't want all of those related colors to show up as individual items, because users will see the same products a number of times.
3. I'd like to create a link within the product page to show the related colors, and their prices.

Any ideas?

(I was thinking of creating an attribute that would contain a comma-separated list of related skus, and loop through them, which would deal with 1 and 3, but I'm still not sure how I would deal with 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up 'Simple Configurable Products'. This is a cool extension that will do exactly what you want to achieve including the image and price options. It is also free.

Comment: This solved the problem in the item page. I guess I stick with my csv approach in the catalog (list) pages. Thanks.